# How drag a window with ALT+click like in Unity in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, usability

How can I arrange windows in a certain position in GNOME 3 manually,
like in Ubuntu 16 with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click?

Comment: Have you tried in GNOME 3? It should work by default. If it doesn't, try <Super>+click&drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same, however with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key rather than the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. If you would rather prefer the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, then you can change that using Gnome Tweaks.

Gnome Tweaks is not installed by default, so you may need to install it first using Ubuntu Software. Launch Tweaks, and you will find the setting "Window action key" on the Windows tab. Change that setting from `Super` to `Alt`.